# What are the best CLI command to clear caches after changes in CSS/LESS in Magento 2.3.3?

Tags: magento2, cache

What is the best and fastest way to make changes visible that has been done in `_theme.less` file ? I always do a lot of things but it is not effective:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade;
php bin/magento setup:di:compile;
rm -rf var/cache;
rm -rf var/composer_home;
rm -rf var/generation;
rm -rf var/page_cache;
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed;
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f de_DE en_GB en_US;
```

Thanks...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Run Below Command**

```
Enable Developer Mode.

1. rm -rf var/* pub/static/*

2. php bin/magento cache:clean
```